# Enable query caching

Tags: hibernate, caching

I need help with caching query in hibernate framework. I`ve set up bellow properties and caching l2 is working in my project.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

I use annotation for entities and when I fetch any MyClass object caching works fine. When I use getOnlyNames method from below interface query caching doesn`t work. Is it possible enable query caching for methods which return eg. list of String (not list of entities, just only selected fields)?

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private long name;
}
```

interface

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
(...)
@Cacheable("getOnlyNames")
@Query("select m.name from MyClass m")
List<String> getOnlyNames();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](http://baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache), if you're trying to cache query results and not objects the syntax is this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select f from Foo f")
  .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)
  .getResultList();
```

As long as you have hibernate query caching configured (which you do), this should work.